# Is it possible to interact with elements of the RStudio IDE itself using R code?

Tags: r, rstudio

Is it possible to interact with the RStudio application using R code inside it? I mean interactions like opening a file in a card, creating a tab for a new unsaved file or changing some text inside an opened tab.

I know a very similar thing can be obtained by just simply creating a new text file or changing its content with R but this way it doesn't interact anyway with the RStudio app itself.

Some context: I was thinking of a tool that could automate inserting some reprexes / snippets of code which could work as a line of code that, when run from a file, replaces itself with a block of code or make a new unsaved file tab and put some code inside it. And yes, I know a very similar thing can be achieved other ways (e.g. simply copying the intended code block into the clipboard) but I'm curious and exploring the possibilities.

Comment: RStudio has a rudimentary [plugin architecture](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/). It exposes a moderately large number of hooks that you can access via R.

Comment: Although I didn't have any plugins in mind, your answer helped me find exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I'm gonna put into an answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the link provided by Konrad Rudolph I managed to find the answer myself.

There is a package called [`rstudioapi`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/rstudioapi/index.html) built into the RStudio that allows many different functionalities and doesn't require using plugins or addins.

All the features can be found in the [official manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstudioapi/rstudioapi.pdf).

Opening a new unsaved file tab with some code in it can be obtained by running:

```
rstudioapi::documentNew(
      "example code here",
      type = "r",
      position = rstudioapi::document_position(0, 0),
      execute = FALSE
    )
```

Inserting code can be easily done with `insertText(text = "")` which inserts `text` at the current position of the text cursor.

Changing one line into another can be obtained with the combination of `getActiveDocumentContext()`, which returns among others the document content and the selection range which is basically equivalent to the cursor position. Then the changing itself can be done with `modifyRange()` respectively to the cursor position and/or the document content.

That allows many possibilities including for example some smoother automation of the workflow.